# Git is acting weird

Tags: git, branch

I'm using git actually for a project. My problem is that Git is acting weird (maybe I'm wrong so let me know please).
So I just created a branch :

```
git checkout -b my_branch
```

I created a file in that branch. But then when I come back to my master branch and that I do a `git status` :

```
git checkout master
git status
```

I can see the file I created in `my_branch`, in the untracked file list of the `master` branch.

Is Git suppose normally to not showing me the change from `my_branch` till I merge?

Indeed, I didn't add yet my file but just created it. It's more clear now because of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just created a file right? You didn't `git add` and `git commit` it in the `my_branch`. Unless you commit the file, the file is not part of the branch you are in, and when you switch branches, the file will still be there in the working directory as untracked.

This is even applicable to files already in the repo. If you make changes to a file, and switch branches, the change will still be there ( barring conflicting changes across branches )

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell git that it actually should track that file in your `my_branch` branch. Otherwise git just ignores it, which is what you see here. You should read up on using git, there is quite a good free book available: [ProGit](http://git-scm.com/book).

Answer (score 2):

An untracked file is, as the name suggests, *not tracked*. Hence, it doesn't belong to any branch. As long as it will be untracked, it'll be shown on the `git status` output for every branch. If you add the file to the active branch and then switch to another branch, you won't see that file.